# .wmv videos not playing in WPF MediaElement control in Windows 8

Tags: wpf, video, windows-8, mediaelement

I am having trouble getting videos to play using the WPF MediaElement on a windows 8 box.  Since the MediaElement control relies on Windows Media Player, I tried to play the video on my Win 8 box in WMP and it plays fine, so it doesnt appear to be a codec problem.  My current theory is it has something to do with WMP, rather than a change I need to make to the code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a test app that I mocked up that also has the problem; it works just fine on windows 7 (loads a black screen that plays when you click it), but fails to do anything in win 8 (white screen with no interaction).  I've tried several different methods of loading the video in before I concluded it probably didn't matter how I did it, this code is just the last revision.  If you want to see the issue yourself (actually, just knowing if its just my windows 8 machine would be very helpful), its a pretty small WPF app and any WMV should work.

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bool opened = false;
        var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);


        currentMediaElement.BeginInit();
        currentMediaElement.Source = new Uri("Video.wmv", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        currentMediaElement.EndInit();
        currentMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = currentMediaElement.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        currentMediaElement.MediaOpened += delegate
        {

            opened = true;
            mre.Set();
        };
        currentMediaElement.Stop();

        mre.WaitOne(5000);
    }

    private void currentMediaElement_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        currentMediaElement.Play();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Name="currentMediaElement" MouseDown="currentMediaElement_MouseDown"></MediaElement>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was either the windows 8 image my company was using or the fact that they were using remote desktop connections to test.  If you're running into this issue I recommend trying to change the test environment!

Comment: I have faced the same issue. It was due to I was testing on remote machine

Answer (score 1):

if your MediaElement is still not working from the above suggestions. I got MediaElement to work by updating my NVDIA Drivers, update the NVDIA drivers then restart and boom my .wmv videos worked again!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with *Windows 8.1*. I searched the web for hours, to no avail. I stumbled into this *StackOverflow* question, and also this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d859208a-0fe9-41d2-b3b2-3ce3a0527c0f/wpf-media-element-is-not-playing-videos-in-xp-but-it-is-playing-in-vista?forum=wpf

#### Quote (emphasis added):

> ...only when the target machine has *Windows Media Player 10* or above
>   **installed**, the *MediaElement* and *MediaPlayer* can work properly.

That lit a light bulb somewhere. I solved the issue by going to `Programs and Features` [*[appwiz.cpl](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/192806)*] `>` `Turn Windows features on or off`, and then enabling *Windows Media Player* under the *Media Features* folder.

The *MediaElement* component is now actually playing videos, as it should (no need to restart).